# Yii2 Themes Advanced Template

Tags: themes, yii2

OK, i know this question has been asked many times, however not one of the answers seems to work, i can only assume Yii2 has been updated since then.

Here goes:
I am trying to change the frontend theme of my Yii2 Advance Application.
I chose a theme from http://yii2.themefactory.net/

I downloaded the theme and completed the following steps that i have found on various sites on the web.

1. Created a folder *myApp/frontend/themes*
2. Placed the files from the download into this folder
3. Changed the *myApp/frontend/config/main.php* to include the following

   ```
   'view' => [
   'theme' => [
       'pathMap' => [
           '@app/views' => '@app/themes/interior'
       ],
       'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/interior',
    ],
   ],
   ```

I have tried various ways of the baseUrl. and it doesn't seem to find the CSS file, as i have read the theme files shouldn't be placed in the web folder.

However i cannot see anyway of reading these CSS files without them being placed in the web folder.

So do i have to split the theme and place the views in the theme folder and then the CSS in another folder under the web folder.

Sorry if this makes no sense, but i have read so many posts across so many sites that all contradict each other.

Let me know any thoughts

Thanks.

Further information.

The issue seems to be that the themes folder *myApp/frontend/themes* contains all the theme files including the CSS. When the website is run it cannot link to these CSS files.

So is the answer that i need to split the themes folder, keep the layouts in the *myApp/frontend/themes* and then put the CSS in a similar folder in *myApp/frontend/web/themes* ??

** **OK Solution - However i am not sue this is the correct way** **

In the theme folder i downloaded there was two folders *layouts* and *files*

I created two folders *myApp/frontend/themes* and *myApp/frontend/web/themes*

I put the layouts folder into the *mayApp/frontend/themes/THEME_NAME* folder and the files folder into *myApp/frontend/themes/web/THEME_NAME/* folder

I then setup the main.php confgi file like this

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/houses-on-water'],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/houses-on-water',
            ],
        ],
```

I am not sure this is the correct way but it is working

Regards

Liam

Comment: have you added the theme asset to the asset?

Comment: how do i do this scaisEgde?

Comment: before of this have check the answer?

Comment: In case the problem is the asset you can check this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57174-yii2-theme-integration/  (but before, try solving the path / url  problem

Answer (score 1):

Copy content in:

> - MYAPP/frontend/web/themes/MYTHEME

Change your MYAPP/frontend/config/main.php

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => [
            //Only for change layout/main.php location
            '@app/views' => '@webroot/themes/MYTHEME'  
        ],
        'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/MYTHEME',
        'basePath' => '@webroot/themes/MYTHEME',
    ],
],
```

Reference:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app
- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-theming

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For `frontend` try changing this way:

```
  'view' => [ 'theme' => [ 
            'pathMap' => [ '@frontend/views' => '@frontend/themes/interior' ], 
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/interior'], 
           ],
```

Comment: i have tried this, its the baseUrl that doesn't seem to work, as i do not have the themes folder under the web folder

Comment: also for baseUrl try using `@frontend` or` @frontend/web/.... ` i think `@app` si for basic app non for advanced

Comment: if i use @frontend it provides me with the path and not the url so it looks for /var/www/html/myapp/web/themes/interior/main_style.css

Comment: what i have found, is that @ frontend and @ backend both are paths and not urls, and the baseUrl needs to be a Url. This in mind i am not sure how to url to a file outside the web folder

Comment: ok using @web/themes/interior i get this <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/themes/interior/files/main_style.css' title='wsite-theme-css' />. with themes/interior i get <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='themes/interior/files/main_style.css' title='wsite-theme-css' />. The issue is there is no folder under the web directory called themes

Comment: but where are the theme folder ? adjust the path/url  for get the correct position

Comment: hiya, OK the theme folder is under myApp/frontend/themes/THEME_FOLDER the issue is that this folder contains all the files for the theme, including the CSS files, when the website is run the CSS cannot be linked

Comment: But you need the theme only  for view or you need a  deficated entry script for some reason? Because if you  use/need a dedicated entry script you should set in this or in asset the css e js. Otherwise i think you don't need baseUrl but eventually you can set the  correct path for css and js in your layout...

Answer (score 0):

Just use theme under web/themes folder, and change your code to this :

```
'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/web/themes/houses-on-water'],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/houses-on-water',
        ],
    ],
```

It's work to me.